# How to constrain type of right hand side parameter of operator implementation?

Tags: generics, rust, polymorphism, traits, parametric-polymorphism

Trying to implement a generic `Vec` implementing the `std::ops::Add` trait. I want the implementation to automatically convert the underlying type of the vector on addition so I can do something like this:

```rust
let u: Vec3<i32> = Vec3 { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };
let v: Vec3<i8> = Vec3 { x: 2, y: 3, z: 4 };
let w = u + v;
```

without using `.into()` at call site. I have implemented the `From` trait (which automatically add the `Into` implementation) and it's working fine on a simple function:

```rust
fn foo<T: Into<Vec3<i32>>>(input: T) -> Vec3<i32> {
    input.into()
}

let v: Vec3<i8> = Vec3 { x: 2, y: 3, z: 4 };
println!("{:?}", foo(v));
```

Link to the **non-compiling** example [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=22ecbeee5b9f965f476142175bb0d7fa). Is it possible to express a constraint on the type of the right hand side argument of an operator and if yes, how?

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

use std::convert::{From};
use std::ops::{Add};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vec3<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    z: T,
}

impl<T: Add<Output=T>> Add<U: Into<Vec3<i32>>> for Vec3<T> {
    type Output = Vec3<T>;
    fn add(self, rhs: U) -> Self::Output {
        let rhs_converted: Vec3<T> = rhs.into();
        Vec3 {
            x: self.x.add(rhs_converted.x),
            y: self.y.add(rhs_converted.y),
            z: self.z.add(rhs_converted.z),
        }
    }
}

impl From<Vec3<i8>> for Vec3<i32> {
    fn from(input: Vec3<i8>) -> Self {
        Vec3 {
            x: input.x.into(),
            y: input.y.into(),
            z: input.z.into(),
        }
    }
}

fn foo<T: Into<Vec3<i32>>>(input: T) -> Vec3<i32> {
    input.into()
}

fn main() {
    let u: Vec3<i32> = Vec3 { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };
    let v: Vec3<i8> = Vec3 { x: 2, y: 3, z: 4 };
    let w = u + v;
    
    // println!("{:?}", foo(v));
    println!("{:?}", w);
}
```

Comment: Please note that automatic type conversions are not considered idiomatic Rust, and are avoided on purpose in the language and its standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `U: Into<Vec3<i32>>` to `U: Into<Vec3<T>>` in your `Add` implementation. Also, the type parameter `U` declaration was missing from the generic `impl`, it should be `impl<T, U>` not just `impl<T>`. After these minor fixes your code works as expected:

```rust
use std::convert::{From};
use std::ops::{Add};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vec3<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    z: T,
}

impl From<Vec3<i8>> for Vec3<i32> {
    fn from(input: Vec3<i8>) -> Self {
        Vec3 {
            x: input.x.into(),
            y: input.y.into(),
            z: input.z.into(),
        }
    }
}

impl<T, U> Add<U> for Vec3<T>
    where T: Add<Output=T>, U: Into<Vec3<T>>
{
    type Output = Vec3<T>;

    fn add(self, rhs: U) -> Self::Output {
        let rhs_converted: Vec3<T> = rhs.into();
        Vec3 {
            x: self.x.add(rhs_converted.x),
            y: self.y.add(rhs_converted.y),
            z: self.z.add(rhs_converted.z),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let u: Vec3<i32> = Vec3 { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };
    let v: Vec3<i8> = Vec3 { x: 2, y: 3, z: 4 };
    let w = u + v;
    println!("{:?}", w); // prints "Vec3 { x: 3, y: 5, z: 7 }" as expected
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69e037f163cfd8364ebc71997115aa18)

Comment: This allows `u + v` but not `v + u`, which cannot easily be added with this implementation.

Comment: @mcarton could it be easily added with a different implementation?